# Can i use fmemopen in emscripten

Tags: c++, unix, emscripten

I need to create  `FILE *f` as memory buffer. I know about `fmemopen`, and want to use it. But I need it in compiled to javascript code. But em++ can't link it. 
I found it in header file in emscripten - [Link to source code](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/system/include/libc/stdio.h&ei=cdsEU_jHJOuGywOHjoCwBg&usg=AFQjCNEZqE74UnnDTCt7W-JvAHxkkKYhLQ&bvm=bv.61535280,d.bGQ&cad=rjt), so I think that somehow I can use it. The question is - how?

PS:

```
FILE * f = fmemopen(buffer, length, 'r');
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of code that doesn't compile?

Comment: Hans, not link in javascript with em++. Added in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a comment, but too long.

The code below compiles with a warning

```
warning: unresolved symbol: fmemopen
```

Is this what you mean by "can't link" or does compilation actually fail?

```
#include "emscripten.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char *r = NULL;
  void * buffer = NULL;
  size_t length = 0;
  FILE * f = fmemopen(buffer, length, r);
}
```

If it compiles, what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Yes, This is what i mean by "can't link". When i run my code (js code) i get: Uncaught ReferenceError: _fmemopen is not defined.